# Stopping paste after any input is exhausted

Tags: bash

I have two programs that produce data on stdout, and I'd like to `paste` their output together. I can successfully do this like so:

```
paste <(./prog1) <(./prog2)
```

But I find that this method will print all lines from both inputs,
and what I really want is to stop `paste` after either input program is finished.

So if `./prog1` produces the output:

```
a
b
c
```

But `./prog2` produces:

```
Hello
World
```

I would expect the output:

```
a Hello
b World
```

Also note that one of the input programs may actually produce infinite output, and I want to be able to handle that case as well. For example, if my inputs are `yes` and `./prog2`, I should get:

```
y Hello
y World
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
while IFS= read -r -u7 a && IFS= read -r -u8 b; do echo "$a $b"; done 7<$file1 8<$file2
```

This has the slightly annoying effect of ignoring the last line of an input file if it is not terminated with a newline (but such a file is not a valid text file).

You can wrap this in a function, of course:

```
paste_short() {
  (
    while IFS= read -r -u7 a && IFS= read -r -u8 b; do
      echo "$a $b"
    done
  ) 7<"$1" 8<"$2"
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work: when I replace `$file1` with `(./prog1)`, I get a syntax error, and if I replace it with `$(./prog1)` I get an ambiguous redirect.

Comment: Seems to be a quirk with process substitution. When I use the function you provided, everything works perfectly!

Comment: @perimosocordiae: If you want it to work from the output of a command, you need to use the process substitution syntax `<(./prog1)`. The `<` is part of the process substitution; to redirect, you need another one: `7< <(./prog1)`. `(./prog1)` is a *subshell* (which needs to be a command by itself) and `$(./prog1)` is *command substitution*, which means that it is replaced literally with the command's output. If you use my `paste_short` function, the invocation would be: `paste_short <(./prog1) file1` (to paste the output of `prog1` and the contents of `file1`).

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Now I can stop blundering around in the shell so much.

Answer (score 3):

Use `join` instead, with a variation on the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
numbered () {
  nl -s- -ba -nrz
}
join -j 1 <(prog1 | numbered) <(prog2 | numbered) | sed 's/^[^-]*-//'
```

Piping to `nl` numbers each line, and `join -1 1` will join corresponding lines with the same number. The extra lines in the longer file will have no join partner and be omitted. Once the `join` is complete, pipe through `sed` to remove the line numbers.

Comment: But be careful!  `nl` produces no output for blank lines.  Try `nl -ba`

Comment: Thanks. Having never used `nl` before, I'm still researching the correct way to call it. However, I'm starting to think this is not a good method if you need to preserve the exact whitespace used in the output of `prog1` and `prog2`.

Comment: For my uses, blank lines aren't a big deal. There is one major issue, though, and that is `join` expects inputs sorted in lex order, not numeric order. When `nl` hits 10, `join` starts to complain.

Comment: Using `-n rz` should pad all the numbers with leading zeros to allow for correct lexicographical sorting. I still don't have a good replacement for the `cut` command.

Comment: OK, replaced `cut` with `sed` and changed the delimiter used by `nl` so that I don't have to deal with how to portably specify a tab in `sed`'s replacement pattern.

Comment: This is still acting strange on my CentOS box, and it looks like it's due to `join` buffering a large number of lines from `yes` (my infinite test case), which is using up all the leading zeros and throwing off the sort again. I wish `join` supported numerical sort!

Comment: sigh. And this seemed so promising at first. :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} FNR>i{exit}
                   {print a[FNR], $0}' <(printf "hello\nworld\n") <(printf "a\nb\nc\n")
hello a
world b
```

Keep the longer output producing program as your 2nd input.